# I don't really understand What does "nearest larger" means (Ruby)

Tags: ruby

I am working on a question, but I still don't understand what exactly this question asks for?

I don't know why expected output for ([2,3,4,8], 2) is equal to 3
Maybe 3 is the nearest number to 2?? or some other number in the array?

I don't understand all the outputs below

Please help me! Thank you so much

This is the question and outputs below:

> Write a function, `nearest_larger(arr, i)` which takes an array and an
>    index.  The function should return another index, `j`: this should
>    satisfy:
>
> (a) `arr[i] < arr[j]`, AND
>    (b) there is no `j2` closer to `i` than `j` where `arr[i] < arr[j2]`.
>    In case of ties (see example below), choose the earliest (left-most)
>    of the two indices. If no number in `arr` is larger than `arr[i]`,
>    return `nil`.
>
> Difficulty: 2/5

```
def nearest_larger(arr, idx)
end

puts("Tests for #nearest_larger")
puts("===============================================")
    puts "nearest_larger([2,3,4,8], 2) == 3: "  + (nearest_larger([2,3,4,8], 2) == 3).to_s
    puts "nearest_larger([2,8,4,3], 2) == 1: "  + (nearest_larger([2,8,4,3], 2) == 1).to_s
    puts "nearest_larger([2,6,4,8], 2) == 1: "  + (nearest_larger([2,6,4,8], 2) == 1).to_s
    puts "nearest_larger([2,6,4,6], 2) == 1: "  + (nearest_larger([2,6,4,6], 2) == 1).to_s
    puts "nearest_larger([8,2,4,3], 2) == 0: "  + (nearest_larger([8,2,4,3], 2) == 0).to_s
    puts "nearest_larger([2,4,3,8], 1) == 3: "  + (nearest_larger([2,4,3,8], 1) == 3).to_s
    puts "nearest_larger([2, 6, 4, 8], 3) == nil: "+ (nearest_larger([2, 6, 4, 8], 3) == nil).to_s
    puts "nearest_larger([2, 6, 9, 4, 8], 3) == 2: "+ (nearest_larger([2, 6, 9, 4, 8], 3) == 2).to_s
puts("===============================================")
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming, it is about understanding a sentence in the English language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters for the method `nearest_input` are:

1. an array,
2. an index to that array.

So in the first example, the method returns the index of the value in the array that is greater than the value at index 2.

So for this array: `[2,3,4,8]`

- The value at index 2 is 4.
- The next highest value is 8.
- The index of the value 8 is 3.

Comment: Thank you for your help! ^_^